# Using Active Directory B2C to secure a Blazor WASM app and Web API

Tags: active-directory, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-client-side

I have a scenario where I have a Blazor WASM (client only) app that is secured via AD B2C.  As per the documentation I have read, I have registered an application in AD B2C (e.g. BlazorApp) and wired the Blazor app to this instance.  This Blazor app makes API calls to a .NET Core Web API where the endpoints are secured (using the [Authorize] attributes).  As per the documentation I have read, I have also registered the Web API in AD B2C (e.g. WebApi) and wired the API to connect to this instance.

The problem I have is that when I authenticate in the Blazor app, and then pass the access/id token through the API calls, the Web API can't authenticate that token (unauthorized error response).  It works when I wire the Web API to connect to the BlazorApp registration (I'm guessing because that is where the token was issued from).  But this seems to go against the recommendation of registering each app/api in AD as a separate registration.

How can I get the WebApi registration to recognise a token issued by BlazorApp?  Am I going about this wrong and should I just wire the Web API to talk to the BlazorApp instance?

***Additional Information:***

Blazor WASM (client) - Program.cs
*(sensitive information removed)*

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            ...

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(@"https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/blazorapp/app.read");
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(@"https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/blazorapp/app.write");
            });

            ...

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

Blazor WASM (client) - appsettings.json
*(sensitive information removed)*

```
{
    "AzureAdB2C": {
        "Authority": "https://<tenant name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
        "ClientId": "<BlazorApp Application ID>",
        "ValidateAuthority": false
    }
}
```

Web API (.NET Core 3.1) - StartUp.cs
*(sensitive information removed)*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

            services.AddControllers();

            ...

        }
```

Web API (.NET Core 3.1) - appsettings.json
*(sensitive information removed)*

**NOTE**: Authentication works when I replace the WebApi Application ID with the BlazorApp Application ID

```
{
    "AzureAdB2C": {
        "Instance": "https://<tenant name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
        "ClientId": "<WebAPI Application ID>",
        "Domain": "<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code for requesting token. ‘It works when I wire the Web API to connect to the BlazorApp registration (I'm guessing because that is where the token was issued from). ’what does that mean?How you added the Web api, my understanding is that at this point your BlazorApp is both the client side and the api side.

Comment: Your Api is  not well configured, you should read this : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C#creating-the-web-api-project-todolistservice

Comment: and this : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C#modify-the-startupcs-file-to-validate-bearer-access-tokens-received-by-the-web-api

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the BlazorApp‘s api permission in the portal, your scope it should be like https://tenant name.onmicrosoft.com/webApiApp.

Comment: @aguafrommars ... what I can't work out from those samples is, is the Web App and Web API registered as two different registrations in AD B2C?

Comment: @ChauncyZhou ... yes, the BlazorApp has a reference to the WebApi scope in the API permissions in the form of <tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/WebApiApp/Users.ReadWrite.  Does this mean I have the Blazor app configured with the wrong scopes in Program.cs?

Comment: yes,you should replace “ https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/blazorapp/app.read” with   "https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/WebApiApp/Users.ReadWrite" in Program.cs

Comment: And in" AzureAdB2C" should be"ClientId": "<Application ID>",,not  "ClientId": "<WebAPI Application ID>",

Comment: After reading a bit more, I'm wondering if this is considered 'Web API Chains" ... which is currently not allowed with AD B2C (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#web-api-chains-on-behalf-of-flow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is not using OBO flow, OBO flow requires three applications, specifically one `client-side` and two `api-side`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

Back to the problem, first of all your problem is misconfigured scope, as the `api-side` app needs to expose its own `api`, the `API` permission on your blazor app side gets access to the `api-side`, so the access to the scope is configured on the `api-side`, so we need to put `https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/webapiapp/app.read` on the scope, your blazor app is only used to configure access.

It works because you use blazor app to request the blazor app's own `api`, which is feasible, although a little strange, to request yourself.

So for your project, the correct request should be like this.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            ...

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(@"https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/webapiapp/app.read");
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(@"https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/webapiapp/app.write");
            });

            ...

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }

{
    "AzureAdB2C": {
        "Instance": "https://<tenant name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
        "ClientId": "<Application ID>",
        "Domain": "<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked.  Both my BlazorApp and WebApiApp were web applications and they both had Implicit Grant enabled (returning both Access Token and ID token).  As soon as I had the delegation (scope) correct, it started to work.